# Relative approval based reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, up-votes

I think it's much more fair that the questions should be also rated in terms of which proportion of the logged users that viewed that page have upvoted the question.

As a question goes older, it has a tendency of becoming more upvoted, and you can't draw a comparison between older pages and new pages.

With this new system you could. This system could be expanded to user's reputation and answer's reputation.

Comment: You can very easily draw a comparison between older questions and newer questions - they're all dated.  And even if someone makes a minuscule edit that doesn't change the content much (and resets the clock, so to speak), it should still be apparent by the ages of the answers on the question.

Comment: @Daniel I think this calculation could be done automatically for me

Answer (score 4):

Disagree. What happens when I view a question after using up all of my daily votes? That question would be unfairly skewed downward because I viewed it but didn't vote on it.

Also, what problem is this trying to solve? Old good questions get more votes? They should! They're good questions!

Comment: If you used your daily votes, your absence will be matched eventually by a possible absence in the other questions, given enough time and views.